# Ubuntu doesn't recognize windows 7/10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, uefi

I've been struggling with ubuntu installation in the last few days. I got a new Lenovo B50-80 with FreeDos and wanted to install Windows 7 or 10 alongside with Ubuntu 14.04 on a Samsung SSD 840 drive.

Here is what I did:

1)Installed Windows 10 by usb then tried to install ubuntu from usb but it didn't recognize windows even though it could see the different partitions. I left some unpartitioned space but when I created the partition it said that it didn't find the Boot partition or something.

2)Tried installing Windows 7 from cd rom and then again ubuntu in both UEFI and Legacy mode but this time it couldn't even see the different partitions and was just showing everything unallocated.

I'm kinda desperate at the moment, any advice?

thanks

Comment: Have you read through the guide to setting up [Dual boot systems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

Comment: Yes of course. Thing is I don't get the option "Install ubuntu alongside Windows" because it is not recognized, and partitions aren't shown but all unallocated space instead.

Comment: K - I don't run dual boot anymore, as I actually found it to be a little cumbersome but instead run Windows in virtual machines.

Comment: I need/want system efficiency so I will stick to dual boot hoping I will manage to set it up!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, since I'm not native english speaker I'm always trying to improve my communication skills, appreciate that.
By the way, the second answer to that post was the one that helped me fixing the hole thing. Thanks!